# get logged in users with spring reactive/webflux security

Tags: spring-security, spring-webflux, spring-session

I am trying to build a small example with the reactive stack of spring. I want to write some kind of audit log for when somebody logged in and out or keep track of "active users", how would I do that? `ServerHttpSecurity` offers a `authenticationSuccessHandler` for `formLogin` and a `logoutSuccessHandler` for logout. But `httpBasic` seems to offer nothing alike. How would I get notified if a session would time out?
In classic spring I would have used the `SessionRegistry` for that, but that seems to be no longer available in the reactive stack.